# Is there a rule to name a cache key

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is there any rule to give proper name for the cache key we use in ASP.Net.

```
 string cacheKey = "aaaabbbbbsssssssss";
 ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
 CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
 cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
 cache.Add(cacheKey, definitions, cacheItemPolicy);
```

Here the cacheKey = needs to be any string..I am concerned about the value of **"cacheKey"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about `HttpContext.Current.Cache`, then no. Generally speaking, it's your application that uses this cache, so you have full control over what you call the keys.

That said: if you're concerned about collisions (e.g. between other assemblies that you're using), consider using a namespace-qualified name -- the typename of the class that owns the cache value might work. Alternatively, you might use a URI -- they're good for relatively unique names, since people are unlikely to use your domain name without meaning to. Of course, there's always GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

u mean to say action filter used in mvc i guess which is used like an attribute

[OutputCache(10)]

or

When overridden in a derived class, tries to insert a cache entry into the cache as a CacheItem instance, and adds details about how the entry should be evicted. (Inherited from ObjectCache.)